# AJAX Update Query every 5 seconds to output album art for Icecast Server

Tags: php, jquery, json, xslt, icecast

**Some background:**

I have Icecast 2.4.3 running on a Windows computer. I have made a "Now Playing" xsl file that resides in the "web" directory of Icecast. An example of a currently playing song that would be in the file would be somethings like this:

```
getMusic({
    "/stream":{
        "server_name":"Radio",
        "title":"Jack Johnson - Crying Shame"}
    });
```

From my webpage, I have a timeout function that will automatically change the artist and song title to a  with an id of "track-title2". This script looks something like this:

```
<script>
function updateTitle() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://radio.domain.com/np.xsl',
        jsonpCallback: 'getMusic',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).then(function (data) {
        var $track = $('#track-title').text(data['/stream'].title);
    }).fail(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).always(function () {
        setTimeout(updateTitle, 5000);
    });
}
$(updateTitle);
</script>
```

ALL THAT WORKS...

Now, I want to step up my webpage by adding album art by accessing a LAST.FM API. This function is in another separate PHP file called "loadme.php".

**The Problem:**

I cannot seem to figure out how to parse my AJAX GET request that (in this example) outputs to the screen Jack Johnson - Crying Shame. I need to grab all characters up to the "-" and similarly, take everything after the "-" and put this into two PHP variable, i.e. $artist and $title (respectively).

Since the artists and titles could change as well, I want this call to be similar to the script above.

**The PHP call in my index.php:**

```
<?php
echo '<img id="albumart" style="text-align:center;" src="';
echo LastFMArtwork::getArtwork('Jack Johnson', 'Crying Shame', true, "small");
echo '">';
?>
```

I have obviously hard coded the title to make sure that the API is correct... it is and the album art does show on my webpage.

**Please help:**
Develop a JSON AJAX script that updates every 5 seconds that calls the PHP function "LastFMArtwork::getArtwork" but can parse out the artist and title into two PHP variables. Any help and/or guidance is *greatly* appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the code that queries `LAST.FM API`?

Comment: You could use `split()` and `trim()`.  Might I suggest a different approach?  Have your PHP script take care of fetching the current metadata, and then combining it with the artwork URL.  Don't send back the HTML for the artwork... send back the artist, title, and URL for the artwork in JSON.  Also, consider using SSE so you don't have to do polling.  It's much more efficient.  (Some script will likely have to poll the Icecast server... but this is just one connection rather than all your listeners polling it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with a little (okay a bunch of) guidance from Brad, I was able to use a hybrid of SSE (Server Sent Events) and AJAX.

**My index.php page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
  <meta name="description" content="Person's personal and professional radio station. ***Contains explicit content***">
  <meta name="keywords" content="icecast,radio,internet radio,station,mediamonkey">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://radio.domain.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://radio.domain.com/ogimage.png" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Radio" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Person's personal internet radio station" />
  <title id="track-title"></title>
  <style>
   html{width:100%;}
   body{background-color:#bfbfbf; text-align:center; font-family:Helvetica;}
   #wrapper{position:absolute; width:300px; height:450px; max-width:550px; max-height:700px; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,0); -ms-transform:translate(-50%,0); -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,0); margin-right:-50%; text-align:center; box-shadow:1px 1px 20px 5px #4d4d4d;}
                        #albumart{position:relative; text-align:center; box-shadow:1px 1px 20px 5px #4d4d4d;}
   #radio{position: relative;}
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
function updateTitle() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://radio.domain.com/np.xsl',
  jsonpCallback: 'parseMusic',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
 }).then(function (data) {
  var $track = $('#track-title').text(data['/stream'].title);
  var text = $track.text();
  $track.text(text.replace(" - MediaMonkey",""));
 }).fail(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
 }).always(function () {
  setTimeout(updateTitle, 12500);
 });
}
$(updateTitle);
function sendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://radio.domain.com/getalbum.php',
        success: function(data){
                document.getElementById("art").innerHTML = data;
  console.log(data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    sendRequest();
                }, 10000);
        }});
};
$(sendRequest);
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <h2>Live Radio</h2>
        <span id="art"></span>
        <audio id="radio" controls src="https://radio.domain.com/stream" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My SSE page that is called from AJAX (getalbum.php):**

```
<?php
require_once("lastfm.php");
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$exe = curl_init();
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_URL, "https://radio.domain.com/np.xsl");
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($exe, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$raw = curl_exec($exe);
curl_close($exe);
$json = $raw;
//The next 7 lines gets rids of all the "extra stuff" from the np.xsl file
$json = str_replace("\n","",$json);
$json = str_replace("\t","",$json);
$json = str_replace("\"","",$json);
$json = str_replace("({","",$json);
$json = str_replace("\n\t","",$json);
$json = str_replace("parseMusic/stream:{title:","",$json);
$json = str_replace(" - MediaMonkey}});","",$json);
//Find the dash and minus one is the artist!
$artist = substr($json, 0, strpos($json, "-") - 1);
//Find the dash and add 2 and that is the title!
$title = substr($json, strpos($json, "-") + 2, strlen($json));
echo '<h4>'.$artist.' - '.$title.'</br></br>';
echo '<img id="albumart" title="'.$title.'" style="text-align:center;" width="280" height="280" src="';
echo LastFMArtwork::getArtwork("$artist", "$title", true, "extralarge");
echo '"></br>';
flush();
```

**Sceenshot from my live website:**
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wwX5.png)